# what are the components of logical mathematical intelligence?

Tags: intelligence, test

what are the components of logical mathematical intelligence?
The logical mathematic intelligence is one among the multiple intelligences suggested by Howard Gardner. I require the components of the same to make a test to measure logical mathematical intelligence of my students.

Comment: Note that Gardner himself has since [retracted his stance](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316422250.037) on multiple intelligences.

Answer (score 2):

This question may be too complex to answer specifically as there are several components that identify Logical-Mathematical intelligence.

In terms of behaviour high LMI people **need** things to explore and think about, and are often seen as manipulative and often seek new experiences or topic matter to discover.  These people **love** to experiment, question, figure out and calculate and often excel in logical or mathematical topics (as the name implies).

Testing for this in isolation may prove to be difficult as question sets focusing on logical reasoning and mathematical prowess may be skewed due to several reasons, including insufficient education to master the mathematics and the fact that given time most people have the ability to respond to LMI based questions.  Its is also very common that people may have a high L sub-component and a low M sub-component and vice-versa.

May I suggest a more holistic way of measuring MI in all it's facets, and then extracting the top LMI performers.  There are a few commercial tests and testing bodies that can help you here.